# Custom dropdown javascript not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm learning javascript and want to create a custom dropdown using javascript. I've made the code as below, but why is it still not working? is there anything missing from the code that I've made?

**EDIT**

There are bugs. First, when I click content from the menu, the dropdown closes. What I want the dropdown close is only when click "Get Started" not the content.

the second, for the first menu, I made active. But when I click on the bottom one, there is like a bug (it doesn't open), but in the second click it's open

```js
$('.list-menu > .menu').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let child = $(this).children('.submenu');
    $(this).addClass("active");

    child.slideToggle('normal');
});
```

```css
.list-menu .menu.active .submenu{
    display:block;
}

.list-menu .submenu{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-menu">
   <li class="menu active">
      <a href="#" class="txt-medium">
         <i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i>
            Getting Started
       </a>
       <div class="submenu">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat suscipit cum nostrum incidunt quasi facere unde exercitationem omnis id nobis ratione veritatis minus corporis, quia quidem perferendis nulla. Laudantium, fuga.
        </div>
     </li>
     <li class="menu">
      <a href="#" class="txt-medium">
         <i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i>
            Getting Started
       </a>
       <div class="submenu">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat suscipit cum nostrum incidunt quasi facere unde exercitationem omnis id nobis ratione veritatis minus corporis, quia quidem perferendis nulla. Laudantium, fuga.
        </div>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, here `children('submenu')` you are missing `.` i.e : `children('.submenu')`

Comment: do you want to create dropdown ?

Comment: i've edited my post above, i'm facing a bug. Can you help me? @Swati

Comment: Just to be clear, you're not learning JavaScript with jQuery, but you learn stuff that is very much related. I recommend that you ditch jQuery for learning JS and concentrate on vanilla JavaScript instead for now. Frameworks of all sorts is the next step once you understand the underlying code.

Comment: Remove this line: `child.slideToggle('normal');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `a` tag as well in your selector i.e : `$('.list-menu > .menu a')` so now only on click of `a` tag dropdown will be open/close . Then , i don't think there is need to add active class because you are handling that part  `child.slideToggle('normal');` so i have removed that and then on page load i have added  `$('.list-menu > .menu:first a').click()` so your first li will be shown by default.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //only on click of `a` tag
  $('.list-menu > .menu a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let child = $(this).parent().children('.submenu'); //use parent..
    child.slideToggle('normal');
  });
  $('.list-menu > .menu:first a').click() //make first li to show..
})
```

```css
.list-menu .submenu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-menu">
  <li class="menu">
    <a href="#" class="txt-medium">
      <i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i> Getting Started
    </a>
    <div class="submenu">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat suscipit cum nostrum incidunt quasi facere unde exercitationem omnis id nobis ratione veritatis minus corporis, quia quidem perferendis nulla. Laudantium, fuga.
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="menu">
    <a href="#" class="txt-medium">
      <i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i> Getting Started
    </a>
    <div class="submenu">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat suscipit cum nostrum incidunt quasi facere unde exercitationem omnis id nobis ratione veritatis minus corporis, quia quidem perferendis nulla. Laudantium, fuga.
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what if the initial conditions are all open?

Comment: Then , simply remove this css `.list-menu .submenu {display: none;}` and on page click line as well .

Answer (score 0):

I have just added `style="display:none;"` in submenu div.

```html
<style>

.list-menu .menu.active .submenu{
    display:block;
}

.list-menu .submenu{
    display:none;
}
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-menu">
   <li class="menu active">
      <a href="#" class="txt-medium">
         <i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i>
            Getting Started
       </a>
       <div class="submenu">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat suscipit cum nostrum incidunt quasi facere unde exercitationem omnis id nobis ratione veritatis minus corporis, quia quidem perferendis nulla. Laudantium, fuga.
        </div>
     </li>
     <li class="menu">
      <a href="#" class="txt-medium">
         <i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i>
            Getting Started
       </a>
       <div class="submenu" style="display:none;">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat suscipit cum nostrum incidunt quasi facere unde exercitationem omnis id nobis ratione veritatis minus corporis, quia quidem perferendis nulla. Laudantium, fuga.
        </div>
     </li>
</ul>
<script>
$('.list-menu > .menu').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let child = $(this).children('.submenu');
    $(this).addClass("active");

    child.slideToggle('normal');
});
</script>
```

Comment: not like that, it's all like my post above nothing has changed.

Comment: There is the change https://prnt.sc/17zi6iy and my code snippet working correctly.